# Text field values in robot framework using selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber, robotframework

I am using Robot-framework selenium2.0.
In the robot test I made, it fills out a form and save it. In the form, I have to put some numeric values in some text boxes but somehow the previous\default value of 0.0 is not removed from any of the box. When I run the test normally it puts the values after 0.0. For example I want to put 50 in the box but the test puts 50 after 0.0 so it becomes 0.050 and when it switches to next text box the value becomes NaN.
Here is how I am doing it,

```
wait until element is visible       text_field     
click element     text_field 
input text        text_field     50
```

Is there any ascii codes that can be used to select values (ctrl+a) and delete the values first and then use input text to input values?

Comment: What do you mean by "with cucumber"? Cucumber is a different testing framework.

Comment: right ! I edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be work for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("text_field")).click()
driver.findElement(By.id("text_field")).pressKey('Ctrl' + 'A')
driver.findElement(By.id("text_field")).pressKey('Delete')
```

more Press Key [here](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/498)

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Clear Element Text text_field
```

More on this [here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Clear%20Element%20Text).

You could also use *Selenium* directly:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("text_field")).clear();
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you getting an error, do you get the same behavior (0.050) ? I assumed `"text_field"` is the id for that field.

Comment: No I do not get any error. I found a way around this. The 'input_text' keyword was not working so I used 'press key' which worked. Whenever I used the 'input_text' keyword the value in box becomes NaN and then 0.0 again when it switches to next text box.
    
    `wait until element is visible       text_field
    double click element                 text_field
    press key                                  text_field              50`